# Hide edges of cube

Tags: graphics3d

Is there an option to hide the edges of a `Cuboid`?

The default behavior is the following:

[image: default cuboid]

And the desired is the following:

[image: desired result]

---

I'm working in [mathics-threejs-backend](https://github.com/Mathics3/mathics-threejs-backend) and we want to add the edges, but we don't know if Mathematica have a option to show/hide them (we'd like to keep a certain "compatibility" of the names).

Comment: Add `EdgeForm[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @cvgmt! `EdgeForm[]` is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/101738)

Comment: @Coolwater that is the only answer, and contains the answer. cvgmt probably suspected it is a simple-mistake or duplicate but till it is closed as such this answer holds, or?